# OnScroll Sticky header while getting back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created this **Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/empafmw8/

I've got everything working fine, but when you scroll back to top of the site, `.sticky-header` will change it's `position` to `relative` when you scroll on 0. But I need to do it, when `.first` will appear on the screen.

I also need it to work, if `.first` would have `height: 100%`

I tried something like `else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 800px)` or `else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 100%)` But it's not working.

Comment: try this - `if($(window).scrollTop() == 800)`

Comment: @Developer107 no, it's not working then. https://jsfiddle.net/50jopbz1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (see comments for my changes):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstHeight = $('.first').outerHeight(); // get the height of the /first div
  //header
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.sticky-header').offset().top && !$('.sticky-header').hasClass('posi')) {
      $('.sticky-header').addClass('posi');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= firstHeight && $('.sticky-header').hasClass('posi')) { // remove the class if the height is less than or equal to the height of the first div
      $('.sticky-header').removeClass('posi');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: red;
}
.second {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  background: blue;
}
.sticky-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}
.posi {
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second">
  <div class="sticky-header"></div>
</div>
```

Or you could just do an if else using your original offset top - just move the `hasClass` to within it: [updated fiddle that's a bit more efficient](https://jsfiddle.net/empafmw8/6/)

Comment: Hello, Pete, this is (almost) perfect! It's working well on example, but when I implement it to my website, it blinks for few pixels. Could you please look at it here? http://zkouskova-domena1.8u.cz/

Comment: Hi Honzis, try the version in my updated fiddle link (below the main code) - it should work a bit better than in my original answer: https://jsfiddle.net/empafmw8/6/

Comment: A bit closer, mentor! I've updated my website. It now acts like script activates like 80px later. So as you can see, it is relative and setted to absolute later. I'm so thanksful for your time!

Comment: Very strange, what browser are you testing with? I tried with chrome and it seems to work fine.  Try removing the hasClass ifs, it may cause a delay if scrolling too fast: https://jsfiddle.net/empafmw8/7/

Comment: Chrome, version 50.0.2661.94. I'm at school atm. And when I remove hasClass, no change. I also tried to scroll slowly. Also Firefox. And Chrome on Android phone.

Comment: Ah yeah I was scrolling too fast - I see the problem! can you add a `console.log(secondTop);` after it is declared - just want to see if it is 1085

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111206/discussion-between-pete-and-honzis-novak).

Comment: Could you please look into the chat for a sec, Pete?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `else if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('.second').offset().top)` - this will make the sticky header go back to its original place as soon as `.first` is onscreen.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50jc9mw8/).

Comment: Thank you! It was complicated more then I expected, everything deeper is solved in Pete's answer. Your answer also worked in that example, so thanks again +1!